# Ellipsize end on edit text in chain in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack, ellipse

I want to achieve this [image: required]

but I am getting this [image]

Here is my XML -

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/root_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".ui.main.DocEditingFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/document_name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/document_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/document_name"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/document_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/save_document_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/save_document_button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/back_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Dummy Documentcjagcjahgckjakjcckoxhaiuab" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/save_document_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/document_name"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/view_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="SAVE" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried to put android:singleLine="true" instead of maxLine attribute but that remove the dots in end.
I also tried to make height 0dp and but still no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, give weight to the edittext,

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_arrow" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABDBDDBDBD"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/save_document_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/document_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="SAVE" />

</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: I have tried this but not able to achieve the result.

Comment: Did you try it using Linear or Relative Layout? @nikhilbansal